# Spark r: one-hot encoding a variable with an ambiguous recognised character of No

Tags: r, apache-spark

I am trying to one-hot encode chlorpropamide but keep getting the error below. I am not sure how to resolve it to create my model.

```
diabetic_data %>% 
  mutate(Steady = ifelse(chlorpropamide == "Steady", 1, 0),
         Up = ifelse(chlorpropamide == "Up", 1, 0),
         Down = ifelse(chlorpropamide == "Down", 1, 0),
         No = ifelse(chlorpropamide == "No", 1, 0))


mn_model = ml_logistic_regression(diabetic_data,
                                 readmitted ~ number_inpatient+ Steady + Up + Down + No
                                  fit_intercept = FALSE)
```

```
Error:
! org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference 'NO' is ambiguous, could be: q01.NO, q01.NO.; line 54 pos 2

Run `sparklyr::spark_last_error()` to see the full Spark error (multiple lines)
To use the previous style of error message set `options("sparklyr.simple.errors" = TRUE)`
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Zzzzuuu. The first line should be `diabetic_data <- diabetic_data %>%` to make `mutate()` permanent. Also, there may be other issues, so if your data aren't confidential, run `dput(diabetic_data[1:5,])` and add the result to your question. If your data are confidential, create a 'dummy' dataset that replicates the structure of your diabetic_data object. Thanks